# Visual Voicemail disappeared after Amber update

Tags: amber-update, nokia-lumia-620

After upgrading my Lumia 620 with the Amber update the Visual Voicemail function went missing. (The cassette symbol appeared again, and there is no on/off VVM setting) I've been in contact with both Nokia and my phone operator (Netcom Norway) and they just point at each other. Anyone else experiencing this? Can I expect this to be fixed in future winphone updates, or is this purely an operator problem?

Answer (score 1):

I use Verizon, which I'm guessing you do too, as I'm pretty sure it's a Verizon specific feature. Search the app store - there's a Verizon "Voicemail" app. If it's not installed, install it. If it is installed, then problem solved.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using verizon, and I'm looking for the builtin VVM feature of winphone.

Comment: I've done a little more research and here's the long and short of it. Visual Voicemail is built into the Windows Phone OS, but you must have carrier support in order for it to be available. Most carriers have opted to build their own app in order to provide that support (Verizon jumped on the wagon fast, AT&T and T-Mobile later). Because Verizon supports VVM through their proprietary app, I don't have the default VVM availability built into the "Phone" app. This is definitely an issue with your carrier. I checked Netcom's website and can not confirm their support for the feature.